# WCF Request body is sometimes a stream and sometimes buffered?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, logging

I have a WCF webservice. I am trying to do some logging whenever a request is received by implementing a MessageInspector and logging in the AfterReceiveRequest() event.

For some reason whenever I send a request to the webservice using the WCFTestClient.exe everything works fine. The message is logged and the request proceeds as normal.

But when I send a request to the webservice using SOAPUI as the client, making a copy of the request message causes the body to simply show `<body>... stream ...</body>` and it fails to be loaded as an XML document later for the sake of validation.

I'm guessing that a request from the WCFTestClient.exe is received with a buffered message body and a request from SOAPUI is received as a streamed body? How is this possible?

- Is there someway I can write some code that will safely make a copy of either version? I have yet to figure out how to safely copy a streamed version as CreateBufferedCopy() obviously does not achieve this.
- Or can I configure WCF to always create a buffered message body and never a stream?

Here is the code I am using to log and copy the request message:

```
object IDispatchMessageInspector.AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
{
    try
    {

        MessageBuffer buffer = request.CreateBufferedCopy(Int32.MaxValue);
        request = buffer.CreateMessage();

        Message copy = buffer.CreateMessage();

        LogRequest(copy);

        ValidateMessage(ref request);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new FaultException<>()...
    }
    return null;
}
```

The copy of the request message fails to be loaded into an XML document within the ValidateMessage() method if it came from SOAPUI with a streamed body. It succeeds to be loaded as an XML document if it comes from WCFTestClient.exe with a buffered body.

```
void validateMessage(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message)
{
    XmlDocument bodyDoc = new XmlDocument();
    //This load throws exception if request came from SOAPUI with streamed body...
    bodyDoc.Load(message.GetReaderAtBodyContents());
    ...
}
```

The exception thrown by the Load() method is:

> System.InvalidOperationException {"The specified node cannot be
>   inserted as the valid child of this node, because the specified node
>   is the wrong type."}
>
> at System.Xml.XmlDocument.AppendChildForLoad(XmlNode newChild,
>   XmlDocument doc)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)    at
>   System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean
>   preserveWhitespace)    at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader
>   reader)    at ...

Comment: How are you logging the message inside your LogRequest method?

Comment: @mlessard Using Microsoft Entriprise Library Logging framework. But it seems to be irrelevant. If I comment out that line, the simple act of copying the message to the "request" variable causes the problem.

Comment: @TerryB: I mean, are you using ToString() on the message? I'm asking this because this is not a correct way to read the message. ToString() will often not return the content of the body, that could be why you get "... stream ..." inside the body. See msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734675.aspx, section "Accessing the Message Body for Debugging".

Comment: Perhaps but I think it's irrelevant right? If I comment out //LogRequest() so no toString() is happening anywhere. The copy I have made of the request fails to be loaded into an XML doc. Whereas if the request comes from the WCFTestClient.exe with a buffered body, it loads into an xml doc just fine. I'll update the question to show the code that fails..

Answer (score 2):

I believe that SOAPUI always sends the message requests it builds as Stream. I do not know for sure if this is something you can modify, either by code on your SOAPUI test or some SOAPUI configuration option/file on SOAPUI.

Ckeck the TransferMode property of your binding as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731913.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx). You could possibly have multiple endpoints using different custom bindings for clients that send you buffered request and stremed requests.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

What's the exception being thrown? The reader returned by `GetReaderAtBodyContents()` is positioned at the first element inside the body, not on the body tag itself. So the way you're loading your message is incorrect because the body could contain more than one node and in that case it will fail.

Just to check, could you use the following code to validate the content of the whole message (the copy) and see if the body contains exactly the same thing when sent from SOAPUI?

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
    {
        message.WriteMessage(writer);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
    }
}
```

If you want all nodes inside the body you might have to create a Body node yourself.

Comment: hi mlessard, I have updated the question with the exception thrown.

Comment: Used your code to write a stream out to file of each request. The request message from SOAPUI is unchanged to before it was copied and it is also identical to the request sent from WCFClient. So, A message from WCFClient can tolerate being copied and still work fine. Whereas a message from SOAPUI will fail to be loaded into an xml doc if it has been copied.  If it hasn't been copied it is also fine. The only difference I can spot between the two scenarios is that the one from SOAPUI shows <body>...stream...</body> when viewed in debugging or using ToString() and the one from WCFClient doesn't.

Comment: I don't know SOAPUI so I can't help you with that. But seeing "...stream..." is normal if you use ToString(). ToString() does NOT always return the content of the body, so don't use it to debug. And it's also normal that your code fails to load the body in a XmlDocument, because what you're passing to XmlDocument.Load() is the content of the body node, not the body node itself. See "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6091212/get-body-from-wcf-message". Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

The GetReaderAtBodyContents() method returns any characters between the closing element of the body and the closing element of the soap envelope.  The XmlReader fails with the exception listed earlier in the thread when it reads past the closing element of the body.

More here:
http://www.katlaconsulting.co.uk/blog/wcfxmlschemavalidation